# Ionic 2 NavBar icon right weird issue

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Lemme get straight to the point so for some reason the icon (button) has a silver background even though i have icon-only i tried 2 code

This put's the home with a blue background and sends it to the left even though i have end = right..

```
<button ion-button icon-only end (click)="home_clicked()">
  <ion-icon name='ios-home-outline'></ion-icon>
</button>
```

This code adds a silver background to the button which doesn't really work looks weird also i need it a little bigger like the blue button...

```
<ion-buttons icon-only end>
  <button icon-only (click)="home_clicked()">
    <ion-icon name="ios-home-outline"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

[image: The problem]

Thank you very much!

Comment: you missed the `ion-button` attribute in the second snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Suraj, you need the `ion-button` attr on your button so they can inherit the Ionic 2 buttons style.